# Surjectivity of the exponential map $\mathfrak{gl}(n, \mathbb{C}) \to GL(n,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: lie-groups, matrix-exponential

This is the first exercise in zeroth chapter of Lie groups beyond introduction by A. knapp: show that exp maps $\mathfrak{gl}(n, \mathbb{C})$ onto $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ but does not map $\mathfrak{gl}(n, \mathbb{R})$ onto $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$.

For the second part, I noted that $exp(\mathfrak{g})$ generates the connected component of the identity, and since $GL(m,\mathbb{R})$ is not connected under the subspace topology induced from $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, the desired conclusion follows.

Is there a sleek proof for the first part, other than using Jordan Canonical form. Moreover, what is the topology on $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$? Is it connected when considered inside $\mathbb{R}^{2n^2}$?
What is the topology one usually means when they refer to $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ ? is it considered inside $\mathbb{R}^{2n^2}$ or $\mathbb{C}^{n^2}$?

Comment: Topologically, $\mathbb{R}^{2n^2}$ and $\mathbb{C}^{n^2}$ are the same. The topology on $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ is the subspace topology. Yes, it is connected. The easiest way to see this is probably by noting that every matrix is similar to an upper triangular one over $\mathbb{C}$ and the upper triangular ones are path-connected. Yes, there are other proofs of surjectivity of $\exp$ over $\mathbb{C}$, e.g. using density of diagonalizable matrices. In any case, these things have all been asked and answered on this site before, so maybe try looking around.

Comment: Your argument for non-surjectivity of $\exp$ on $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ is correct. It might also be worthwhile (and less easy) to note that it is not even surjective onto $\mathrm{GL}^+(n,\mathbb{R})$, the identity component.